# Get many chart on the same template

Tags: php, highcharts, symfony

i'm a beginner on HighchartBundle of Symfony and i've a problem by showing many charts on the same template and resize it.
this is my code:

PHP code

```
class DetailController extends Controller
{   
    public function listObjetAction(Request $request, $id, $monnaie){
    $convert = $this->container->get('waza_comptabilite.change');
    $repository1 = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getManager()
                        ->getRepository('WAZAComptabiliteBundle:Monnaie');
    $listmonnaie = $repository1->findBy(array(), array('code' => 'asc'), null, null);

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getManager()
                        ->getRepository('WAZAComptabiliteBundle:Production');
    $production = $repository->find($id);

    $repository2 = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getManager()
                        ->getRepository('WAZAComptabiliteBundle:Possederobjgain');
    $repository3 = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getManager()
                        ->getRepository('WAZAComptabiliteBundle:Possederobjdep');       
    $objGain = $repository2->findBy(array('gain' => $production->getGain()->getId()), array('date' => 'asc'));
    $objDep = $repository3->findBy(array('depense' => $production-    >getDepense()->getId()), array('date' => 'asc'));
    $infosGain = new DataChart();  
    $infosGain = $this->getInformations($objGain);
    $infosDep = new DataChart();  
    $infosDep = $this->getInformations($objDep);
    $seriesGainMois = array(
        array("name" => "Data Serie Name", "data" => $infosGain->getDatasmois(), "labels" => $infosGain->getLabelsmois())
    );
    $seriesGainAnnee = array(
        array("name" => "Data Serie Name", "data" => $infosGain->getDatasannee(), "labels" => $infosGain->getLabelsannee())
    );
    $seriesDepMois = array(
        array("name" => "Data Serie Name", "data" => $infosDep->getDatasmois(), "labels" => $infosDep->getLabelsmois())
    );
    $seriesDepAnnee = array(
        array("name" => "Data Serie Name", "data" => $infosDep->getDatasannee(), "labels" => $infosDep->getLabelsannee())
    );

    $chGainMois = new Highchart();
    $chGainMois->chart->renderTo('linechart');
    $chGainMois->title->text('Gains en fonction des mois');
    $chGainMois->xAxis->title(array('text'  => "Mois"));
    $chGainMois->yAxis->title(array('text'  => "Montant des gains"));
    $chGainMois->series($seriesGainMois);
    $chGainMois->xAxis->categories($infosGain->getLabelsmois());

    $chGainAnnee = new Highchart();
    $chGainAnnee->chart->renderTo('linechart');
    $chGainAnnee->title->text('Gains en fonction des mois');
    $chGainAnnee->xAxis->title(array('text'  => "Mois"));
    $chGainAnnee->yAxis->title(array('text'  => "Montant des gains"));
    $chGainAnnee->series($seriesGainAnnee);
    $chGainAnnee->xAxis->categories($infosGain->getLabelsannee());

    $chDepMois = new Highchart();
    $chDepMois->chart->renderTo('linechart');
    $chDepMois->title->text('Deps en fonction des mois');
    $chDepMois->xAxis->title(array('text'  => "Mois"));
    $chDepMois->yAxis->title(array('text'  => "Montant des gains"));
    $chDepMois->series($seriesDepMois);
    $chDepMois->xAxis->categories($infosDep->getLabelsmois());

    $chDepAnnee = new Highchart();
    $chDepAnnee->chart->renderTo('linechart');
    $chDepAnnee->title->text('Deps en fonction des mois');
    $chDepAnnee->xAxis->title(array('text'  => "Mois"));
    $chDepAnnee->yAxis->title(array('text'  => "Montant des gains"));
    $chDepAnnee->series($seriesDepAnnee);
    $chDepAnnee->xAxis->categories($infosDep->getLabelsannee());




    $monnaie2 = $monnaie;
    $date = $convert->getDate();
    $pus = array();
    foreach($objGain as $o){
        $monnaie1 = $o->getObjet()->getMonnaie()->getCode();
        $pus[] = $convert->convertValue($o->getObjet()->getPu(), $monnaie1, $monnaie2);
    }
    if($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {         
        return new JsonResponse(array('datas' => $production, 'src' => 'prod_op', 'id' => $id, 'pus'=>$pus,  'maj'=> $date, 'monnaies'=>$listmonnaie, 'monnaie'=> $monnaie, 'modal'=> false));
    }
    return $this->render('WAZAComptabiliteBundle:Core:list_ob_prod.html.twig', array('datas' => $production, 'objGain' => $objGain,
        'objDep' => $objDep, 'src' => 'prod_op', 'chartGainMois' => $chGainMois, 'chartGainAnnee' => $chGainAnnee
            , 'chartDepMois' => $chDepMois, 'chartDepAnnee' => $chDepAnnee, 'id' => $id, 'pus'=>$pus, 'monnaies'=> $listmonnaie, 'monnaie'=> $monnaie, 'modal'=> false));
}
```

Twig, HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="chart">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            {{ chart(chartGainMois) }}
            {{ chart(chartGainAnnee) }}
            {{ chart(chartDepMois) }}
            {{ chart(chartDepAnnee) }}
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I see only the first chart.
Please, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you use renderTo and put the same id for 4 chart it is normal, you have to give a different name

```
$chGainAnnee->renderTo('linechart1')
$chGainMois->renderTo('linechart2')
$chDepAnnee->renderTo('linechart3')
$chDepMois->renderTo('linechart4')
```

and

```
<div id="linechart1"> </div>
<div id="linechart2"> </div>
<div id="linechart3"> </div>
<div id="linechart4"> </div>
```

Comment: you're welcome you can change the state of the question to resolve.